# Unable to select mouse over elements in Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mouseover

I am automating a web application using selenium webdriver and java. It has few mouse over elements which I am not able to automate. Mouse over works well and newly visible elements locate properly when I record and play in Selenium IDE but same is not working when I run in eclipse. I have automated similar mouse over elements earlier but facing difficulty in automating this. I have attached screenshot of a web application and the code for mouse over elements and here I am not able to mouse over on "Configuration" menu and select "Configure Hierarchy Metadata". It would be really great if anybody could help me out in this!! Let me know if any more details needed.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Mouseover menu and code]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue.  You need to make sure you are interacting with the element that has the hover listener..

In this case, it looks like it is the `<a>` that is receiving the hover.  Try moving to element (hovering over):

```
By.cssSelector("ul.topmenu li:nth-child(2) > a[title='Configurations']");
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you will first have to hover on element(say - element1) which makes element to be clicked(say - element2) on visible and then click on the option from list -

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element1).moveToElement(element2).click(element2).build().perform();
```